# Display List of Images/Array of Images from PostgreSQL database using spring boot and angular 8/9

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, angular8, angular9

Fetching the list of images from the database using spring boot and trying to display those images through angular but am unable to succeed from the below code. I found the many blogs and forums which are all doing sending one image and retrieving that image but not the bunch of images.

> The code below am using to achieve my goal.

**1) pic_byte one of the column has stored in the database**

[image: pic_byte one of the column has stored in the database]

**2) Trying to fetch the pickByte**

[image]

**3) Trying to send this list of images to the angular.**

[image]

> Angular Code

Declared **retrievedImage** as **any** and trying to display the image.

[image]

**html code**

[image]

If i do like as described then, I am receiving the warning with error like below.

[image]

**EDIT:**

RAW CODE

1. **Repository**

   @Repository
   public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductsModel, Long>{

   ```
    @Query("select picByte from ProductsModel pm")
     public List<byte[]> getImages();
   ```

   }
2. **Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/retreiveAllImages")
 public List<byte[]> getAllImages() {
 List<byte[]> list = productRepository.getImages();
 return list;
}
```

3. 

> **Angular Code**

```
retrievedImage: any;
getImages() {
this.productService.getAllImages().subscribe((data => {
this.retrievedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
 }))
}
```

4. **HTML Code**

```html
<div *ngIf=retrievedImage>   
<img [src]="retrievedImage"  width="200" height="300"/>
</div>
```

5. Error I received from the above code.

```html
unsafe:data:image/jpeg;base64,GET unsafe:data:image/jpeg;base
```

So, Anyone help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste in the raw code using the appropriate format instead of using screenshots

Comment: I have added the RAW code. Once i received much help, I will try to remove all the images. Thanks.

Comment: But if you have encoded it with base64 it is just a String right? and not a byte array?

Comment: Yes, But that code will work for single image not for the list/array.(Base64 is String method is designed to process a single byte array), but exactly how to show it for the stream of array/list in angular am checking.  If you have any idea. Please let me know.